# t-sql datetime question

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
@EndDate = 2010-05-31
```

select * 
        from TableName
        where OrderNo = 'AB103'
            and month(SendDate) = month(dateadd(mm,-1,@EndDate))

is returning 2 values which has same month (which is April) but different years
  like 2010 and 2009.

How can I change this query so that it returns value only of year 2010 and month remains April?

I have used (CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),(dateadd(mm,-1,2010-05-31)),112)+'01') 
instead for 2010-04-01
What is wrong with this code? 
SendDate = (CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),(dateadd(mm,-1,2010-05-31)),112)+'01')

I dont need value in 2010-04-01 form 
I want it in this form (CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),(dateadd(mm,-1, @EndDate)),112)+'01') 
What mistake I am making?

Anyone??

Comment: Date literals need to be enclosed in strings. 2010-05-31 is 2010 subtract 5 subtract 31, which is May 29, 1905.

Comment: I just added more details to my question

Comment: put the date with ' like  select (CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),(dateadd(mm,-1,'2010-05-31')),112)+'01')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "between" to limit the range of dates:

```
select *
  from TableName
  where OrderNo = 'AB103' and SendDate between '4/1/2010' and '4/30/2011'
```

Note that this assumes you are storing dates without times.  It would not return a SendDate that was during the afternoon of 4/30/11.

Comment: I have used (CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),(dateadd(mm,-1,2010-05-31)),112)+'01') instead for 2010-04-01 What is wrong with this code? SendDate >= (CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),(dateadd(mm,-1,2010-05-31)),112)+'01')

Comment: I dont need value in 2010-04-01 form  I want it in this form         (CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),(dateadd(mm,-1,2010-05-31)),112)+'01')   What mistake I am making?

Comment: you forgot put date in '' I mean 2010-05-31 is math expression. you should put '2010-05-31'

Answer (score 4):

Use an explicit range check:

```
select *
  from TableName
  where OrderNo = 'AB103' 
   and SendDate >= '20100401' 
   and SendDate < '20100501';
```

This is correct and also efficient because this expression is SARGable and can leverage an index on the SendDate column. Using explicit comparison operators avoid the ambiguity of `between` operator (does it include the right side or not? I can never remember, so avoid it altogether). Also using the canonical date format 'yyyymmdd' avoids any issue from running your code on different locales ([`SET DATEFORMAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)).

Comment: +1 - range is by far the safest option (as is yyyymmdd), and has the potential to be the best performing (it can be no worse than the non-sargable options).

Comment: I have added more detail to my question

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
      select * from TableName 
      where OrderNo = 'AB103' 
          and DateDiff(month, SendDate, '2010-04-01') = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way

```
select *
  from TableName
  where OrderNo = 'AB103' 
    and DatePart(yyyy,SendDate) = 2010 
    and DatePart(m,SendDate) = 4
```